# Pick up the not frozen discard pile having a Canasta meld

Tags: canasta

My wife and I have gotten into a bit of an argument.
If the discard deck is not frozen, and I have already met the minimum meld whether that be 50, 90 or 120, can I pick up the discard deck with a natural card and a wild card?
We are trying to use Hoyle to play by.

Comment: Which Hoyle? Hoyle to game rules is like Webster to a dictionary - tells you nothing without also knowing the publisher name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can; this is one of the main differences between the discard pile being frozen or not.

[Source](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/):

> When the discard pile is not frozen against their side, a player may take it: a) with a natural pair matching the top card as above; or b) **by melding the top card with one matching natural card and one wild card from his hand**; or c) by adding the top card to a meld they already have on the table.

[Source 2](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#classic-play):

> But first let us consider the case where the discard pile is not frozen against you. In that case, if the top card of the pile is a natural card (from four up to ace), you can take the pile if either:
>
> 1. you play two cards from your hand that make a valid meld with the top discard: these could be either two natural cards of the same rank as the top discard, **or one such natural card and one wild card**,
>
> or
>
> 2. the top discard matches the rank of one of your partnerships existing melds, and you add it to that meld.

If the pile is frozen; then you must have 2 naturals in hand.